# Editoptions displaying but not taking in the value selected in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid dropdownlist that is being populated with Json data from my database. It displays perfectly but when an option is clicked it does not take in the value selected and send it through. In other words it is just displaying in the drop down and nothing more. Here is my code for the colmodel field I am working with:

```
 {
          name: 'employee_speciality', index: 'employee_speciality', editable: true,
          editrules: { required: true },
          sortable: true,
          align: 'center',
          editable: true,
          cellEdit: true,
          edittype: 'select',
          formatter:'select',
          editoptions: { 
                  dataUrl:"http://localhost:8080/service.svc/serviceBranch",
                  buildSelect: function (response) {
                  var data = typeof response === "string" ?
                  $.parseJSON(response) : response,
                  s = "<select>";
                  s += '<option selected="selected" style="display:none;">Choose here</option>';
                       $.each(data.serviceBranchResult, function () {
                             s += '<option value="' + this.service_name + '">' + this.service_name + 
                             '</option>';
                  })

         return s + "</select>";
    }
  }
}],
```

This is where I am retrieving the data, where employee_speciality is the only one with the dropdownlist:

```
function saveData() {

                            var rowid = $("#jqgrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                            var rowData = $("#jqgrid").getRowData(rowid);

                            var employee_name = rowData.employee_name;
                            var employee_surname = rowData.employee_surname;
                            var employee_username = rowData.employee_username;
                            var employee_email = rowData.employee_email;
                            var branch_id = rowData.branch_id;
                            var user_type = rowData.user_type;
                            var employee_state = rowData.employee_state;
                            var employee_speciality = rowData.employee_speciality;


                            alert(employee_speciality); //to check

                                var gridData = {
                                    employee_name: employee_name,
                                    employee_surname: employee_surname,
                                    employee_username: employee_username,
                                    employee_email: employee_email,
                                    branch_id: branch_id,
                                    user_type: user_type,
                                    employee_state: employee_state,
                                    employee_speciality: employee_speciality

                                };

                                gridData = JSON.stringify(gridData);





                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "Employees.aspx/save",
                                    data: gridData,
                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    success: function (response, textStatus, xhr) {
                                        alert(employee_speciality);
                                        location.reload(true);
                                    },
                                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                        alert(employee_speciality);
                                        Abort();
                                        alert("Please enter all fields");

                                    }
                                })
```

Please can I get some insight as to why this is happening, any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: `"it does not take in the value selected and send it through"` - What does that even mean?  Can you elaborate on the problem?  It sounds like the operation which is actually failing is separate from the code being shown.

Comment: @David The value that is being selected from the dropdown list on the web page is being taken in as null. I have placed alert boxes where the value should be parsed but it just displays nothing in those boxes. Which means that the value selected is not being parsed at all. I can also add the code where I am reading those values.

Comment: I don't see any alert boxes in the code posted in the question.  What does the actual `select` element (with its `option` elements) end up being at runtime?  What is the actual code that runs when you notice the problem?

Comment: Let me add that code. Although when I insert the options statically it worked fine, so i assumed that code would not be the problem.

Comment: @David Here is the code where I use the value. It works perfectly when no dropdownlist is used and also when the dropdown is defined statically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. Taking out the formatter: 'select' worked for me. Thanks for your time @David